# any reason why 'og:image' would NOT work when inside a canvas' html

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple html page/app with all of the common meta:og tags.

PROBLEM: og:image is not getting picked up when app is run within fb.

the app can be accessed via:
1 --- the fb linter ... WORKS ... http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.keleia.com%2Fapps%2Ffacebook%2Fapp_canvas_celjska_puzzle%2F
2 --- the app within fb ... DOES NOT WORK ... http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/;

I use window.open( "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=..." , ...  ).

if you wish to test the problem ... visit either url2 from above; look at bottom left corner of the app there are 2 fb text buttons ... use the RIGHT-most of the two fb links ( "Share With Your Friends" OR "Deli s Prijatelji", depending on language prefs. ).

any thoughts as to why the og:image IS NOT showing up when I use the app inside of fb iframe/canvas??

thanks for your time,
Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old "sharer" which doesn't let you directly manipulate the image you want to share. The opengraph tags will not work as intended in this case because your tags are on your domain while you are trying to share the "apps.facebook.com" domain.

Use the feed dialog referenced below. You will be able to display the exact content you want:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Sid ... that was it .... but how did you know that I had hardcoded the share address ( var u = 'http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/' )?

Comment: unfortunately the feed url doesn't work ... the example you linked to does work from my website ... but once I put my link and my app id I get an error message from facebook - but that is another issue I know.